# C++ hunspell spell-checking library with CHtmlEditCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, hunspell

I needed a lightweight HTML editor to generate "rich text" emails, the catch being that I need to be able to extract and inject the content as HTML. This also needed to have spellchecking.

Previously I had been able to achieve this without spellchecking using an ActiveX control, however since MFC has the `CRichEditCtrl` and `CHtmlEditCtrl`, I determined I would have much more luck with the spellchecking going down this route.

So I have attempted to utilise the hunspell library and have had reasonable success. However I have only been able to get it working with `CRichEditCtrl`. Trying to create an HTML editor out of this RichEditCtrl has proven difficult, and I can't believe that there is no way to interact with a `CHtmlEditCtrl`.

Can anyone recommend any documentation or sample projects that have achieved this? I have sort of been able to hack it in using a `CHtmLEditCtrl` underneath the `CRichEditCtrl`, but this has just caused more problems. Thanks! Hope I've explained myself properly.